# Edit notification content from "Leaves Second Approve"

Tags: odoo-12

I want to change the content of the notification, which is sent after the second approval **(Double Validation).**

This is how the process looks like: When the `HR-Manager` approves the leave, an email is sent to the followers. The current content of the email is something like the following:

```
"Status: Second Approval -> Approved"  (in german "Status: Zweite Genehmigung -> Genehmigt")
```

I want to change the content of this email, but I don't know how. Is there a way to change the content without changing the python code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your email templates.

Go into debug mode: Main Menu > Settings > Activate the Developer mode button

Then go to go back to Settings menu: Main Menu > Settings > Technical (menu up top)

Find Templates (in Email section)

Then find your email templates and change it.

Comment: There is no template for this email. I already checked it but thank you.

Comment: @EmmaM There should always be a template to send email. Else odoo don't know what to send. If odoo is sending an email, it uses the one of the template email, that's how odoo knows what to send.

Comment: Yes I totally understand, but the settings menu for templates doesn't contain the one I'm looking for.

Comment: @EmmaM So does it actually email? Or just notification? The notifications are in file /addons/hr_holidays/models/hr.py search for Second Approval. The views are in /addons/hr_holidays_views/hr_leave_allocation_views and search validate1 You can change the string to have it show something else. If it's email, then you need to create an automated action, and find where it is triggered, and create action for that to auto email (this is complicated).